# Distorted shapes/lines when rescaling - tried previous answers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, scale

[image: Rescaled flag]

I am curious as to why when I scale things the general shape changes. The flag in the middle is what I originally started with, and either side is the distorted result of rescaling it.

I have read previous answers and tried: unchecking align to pixel grid upon start-up of new document and then with the flag shape selected; checking 'scale strokes and effects'.

Any ideas? Here is another example of where this has happened, both lines and rectangle shapes have changed (harder to see):

[image: Rescaled building]

And here is what is checked/unchecked:

[image: Startup menu]

I am completely lost... been searching for an answer but nothing. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - the last screen shot shows that I have 'align new objects to pixel grid' checked - but I have unchecked that now, and still nothing.

Comment: You can edit your question to include this information; people do not always read the comment-fields.

Answer (score 1):

Select everything, **then** uncheck `Align to Pixel Grid` on the **Transform Panel**, *then* scale.

You have to first select *existing* objects to turn off the pixel grid alignment for them if it was on when they were drawn. Simply unchecking `Align New Objects to Pixel Grid` does **not** disable the alignment for anything you've already created.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I had tried that also, also tried creating the object again with 'align to pixel grid' unchecked, but still as I scale it, the shape distorts. What seems to have worked is pathfinder > merge, and then scaling. That may have been an obvious step to take, not sure!

Comment: You shouldn't need any Pathfinder operation. There must be something else happening, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you view this with a strange zoom value. Try viewing your work with these zoom values: 400%, 200%, 100%, 50%, 25%, 12,5% and so on. Computers have hard time deciding what to do with 2px line scaled 33% = 0.66px, so the computer must choose 1px which is 50%. Artifacts always appear in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if this is a screen rendering artifact and not the actual vector paths. Turn on show path edges, turn off pixel preview, view at 100%, and see if components of the flag are identical in height in the inspector view.