# Distorted shape after using pathfinder (illustrator cc)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I have this shape (no strokes): [image]

when I use the pathfinder unite tool the image is distorted to the following:

[image]

I have unchecked align to pixel grid, scale rectangle corners and scale stroke from the transformer control panel.

I've looked online for an explanation but can't seem to find one. Anyone has an idea for this?

Comment: Can you screencap this showing the outlines and anchor points? I think your issue is with 2 anchor points that you think are one. Zoom in on that funky corner and see what's going on in there.

Comment: Is **Align to Pixel Grid** on?? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/distorted-shapes-lines-when-rescaling-tried-previous-answers?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out eventually. The problem was when I created the document I assigned it to a web profile; therefore, the pixels are align to a grid even if I had removed the align to pixel grid function. I created a new document, but this time with a print profile and the problem was solved. I wasn't aware of this feature until now. Thanks the help!

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This has been killing me for a long time. Illustrator can make no sense sometimes.